# SMPP Simulator: How to check connection reset?

Tags: smpp

Im using the smpp simulator tht comes with the Logica smpp api as a virtual smsc. The simulator is not able to detect any connection resets, whn a smpp client disconnects abrupty without sending an unbind PDU. The SMSCSession class in the simulator does not handle/catch any exceptions, while sending a PDU such as DeliverSM. So, how do you identify if there is socket error.

On the smpp client side, u have enquirelink pdu to check for the connection. Similarly, is there any option to check for the connection from the simulator side..

Thanks,
Vishnupriya

Answer (score 6):

I've been using this SMPP simulator:

[SMPP sim](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html)

It works very well, and detects a lot of ill-formed PDU's. Also connection resets are detected.